# mocking a constructor to see if it throws an exception

Tags: java, android, mockito

```
Java 8
```

I have the following constructor I want to test using Mockito.

I want the test to throw an exception if a null is passed for the repository.

```
public PresenterImp(@Nonnull IRepository repository, IScheduler scheduler) {
        super(schedulerFactory);
        this.repository = Preconditions.checkNotNull(repository);
 }
```

What would be the best way to do this? As my presenter is not a mock so I can’t use a when..

In my setup I do the following:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {              
    repository = Mockito.mock(IRepository.class);                     
    iScheduler = Mockito.mock(IScheduler.class);
    viewContract = Mockito.mock(ViewContract.class);                     
    presenter = new PresenterImp(repository, iScheduler);     
              optInNotificationPresenter.attachView(viewContract);  
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: no mock is needed, just pass a `null` in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it as:

```
 @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class )
 public void testNullCheck() throws Exception
           new PresenterImp(null, mock);   

    }
```